# How to change Outlook Calendar Color in C#?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, colors

I'm writing some C# code to view/add/edit AppointmentItems in Microsoft Outlook 2007. I'm accessing a secondary calendar (MAPIFolder), and I would like to programmatically change the color of the calendar. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myNamespace = outLookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
if (myNamespace.Categories["liveMeeting"] == null)
{
  myNamespace.Categories.Add("liveMeeting", OlCategoryColor.olCategoryColorDarkRed, OlCategoryShortcutKey.olCategoryShortcutKeyNone);
}
newEvent.Categories = "liveMeeting";
```

Answer (score 0):

Appointments in Outlook are colored, not calendars. Colors are set based on the Categories assigned to the appointment, so I think using AppointmentItem.Categories would allow you to set the color applied to the appointments you create.